# Python: How do I remove a key from a list of dictionaries based on it's value in all dictionaries in that list

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, one-liner

I've a list of dictionaries like

```
my_list = [{'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd': 0}, 
           {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd': 0},
           {'a':0, 'b':3, 'c':0, 'd': 0}
]
```

i want to remove all keys which are 0 in ALL dictionaries. e.g. the output should be

```
my_list = [{'b':2, 'c':1}, 
           {'b':0, 'c':0},
           {'b':3, 'c':0}]
```

There could be multiple keys that needs to be removed.
But the keys will be same for all the dictionaries present in the list.
So far i've tried nested loops for this e.g.

```
keys = list(stats[0].keys())
keys_to_remove = []
for key in keys:
    key_total = 0
    for stat in stats:
        key_total += stat[key]
    if key_total == 0:
        keys_to_remove.append(key)

return [{k: v for k, v in entry.items() if k not in keys_to_remove} for entry in stats]
```

But I need a optimised solution for this. The one I'm currently using seems really odd to me, is there any shorter way of doing it ? e.g list comprehension or one liner loops etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With nested `zip` (to combine same key entries) and `any` functions:

```
res = list(map(dict, zip(*[t for t in zip(*[d.items() for d in my_list]) 
                           if any(v[1] != 0 for v in t)])))
```

---

```
[{'b': 2, 'c': 1}, {'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'b': 3, 'c': 0}]
```

Comment: it's working thankyou so much. What if I want to skip first key value pair from every dictionary ? as in want to keep it in the result dictionary but just skip from comparison ?

Comment: @F.Shahid, as for *"to skip first key value pair"* - share how the result should look in that case

Answer (score 0):

pandas can do this with very little code and should offer some optimizations:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [{'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd': 0}, 
           {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0, 'd': 0},
           {'a':0, 'b':3, 'c':0, 'd': 0}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
print(df.loc[:, (df!=0).any(axis=0)].to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Output:

```
[{'b': 2, 'c': 1}, {'b': 0, 'c': 0}, {'b': 3, 'c': 0}]
```